# Variable "$id" got invalid value "1"; Int cannot represent non-integer value: "1"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, mern

I've been learning the mern stack from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484243900)

I'm now on Nested Routes under React Router chapter

The web application is supposed to render this on the page.

[image: c1]

[image: c2]

When clicking the `Select` link under the `Action` column, the description of
an issue is displayed on the bottom part of the page.

But in my case, this thing happens:

[image: w-err]

and at the same time this error is being thrown in the console:

[image]

The only time the web application runs properly is when I downgraded the
graphql version to **0.13.2** (this is the version the book uses).

The thing is I try to use up to date versions of the project dependencies
as much as possible. There has never been much trouble as I follow the book
until I got into this.

I don't understand, why is this error being thrown when I use a more up to
date version of the graphql over the old version?
(I use graphql version **15.8.0** and apollo-server-express version **2.25.4**)

I tried to modify the .jsx file that renders the description data
on the page.

```
async loadData() {
  const { match: { params: { id } } } = this.props;
  //I tried to parse the id to make it an int type before getting it into
  //the graphql query
  id = parseInt(id); // this is the thing that I've added
  const query = `query issue($id: Int!) {
    issue (id: $id) {
      id description
    }
  }`;

  const data = await graphQLFetch(query, { id });
  if (data) {
    this.setState({ issue: data.issue });
  } else {
    this.setState({ issue: {} });
  }
}
```

This is the codes graphQLFetch function

```
const dateRegex = new RegExp('^\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d');

function jsonDateReviver(key, value) {
  if (dateRegex.test(value)) return new Date(value);
  return value;
}

async function graphQLFetch(query, variables = {}) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(window.ENV.UI_API_ENDPOINT, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
    });
    const body = await response.text();
    const result = JSON.parse(body, jsonDateReviver);

    if (result.errors) {
      const error = result.errors[0];
      if (error.extensions.code === 'BAD_USER_INPUT') {
        const details = error.extensions.exception.errors.join('\n');
        alert(`${error.message}:\n ${details}`);
      } else {
        alert(`${error.extensions.code}: ${error.message}`);
      }
    }
    return result.data;
  } catch (e) {
    alert(`Error in sending data to server: ${e.message}`);
    return null;
  }
}
```

When I did this, it doesn't throw any error anymore but it doesn't render
the description data on the page either.

Can someone please help me with this?? Thanks in advance...

Comment: `id = parseInt(id);` should be throwing an error since you declared `id` as a `const`

Comment: @Phil can you also tell me why on older version of graphql (0.13.2), the application works properly even without parsing the `id` to `int`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 const query = `query employee($id: Int!) {
      employee(id: $id) {
            age
            dateOfJoining
        
      }
    }`;
use const id=parseInt(this.props.match.params.id);
const data = await graphQLFetch(query, {id});


async function get(_, { id}) {
  const result = await db
  .collection("employee").
  findOne({id:id});
  return result;
  }
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    employee: get,
  },

};
```